# how to save info from local html file in a text document with python?

Tags: python

i have an html file that i want to read the data from and store all information inside it in a separate text file called for instance "test".

the html file i have is not a url but a downloaded html page.

here is what i tried so far:

```
import urllib.request
import shutil



urllib.request.urlretrieve("test.html", "test.txt").
```

this method is giving me an error that reads: `"unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url"`

how can i do this the right way?

Comment: You can use a `file:///` URL

Comment: If the page is already downloaded, why do you need to store the information inside it?  Do you just need to copy the file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "store all information inside it"?  Are you trying to parse out specific elements?

Comment: @0x5453 i want the contents of the webpage to be stored in the text file. and yes then i would like to parse out specific elements, thats why i need all the information first in a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML files are already created using text, so all you would have to do is copy the file and rename it.

```
with open("test.html","r") as f:
    data = f.read()

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in data:
        f.write(line)
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer,i think this is what i need, but i am getting one error saying that "module 'os' has no attribute 'join'". how can i fix this?

Comment: I left out "path". The correct method is os.path.join(), but that's not really necessary for proof of concept. You could just use open("test.html","r"). Fixed the code.

Comment: do i have to put the absolute path of the html file? or keep it where the code file is? cause now i am getting this error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 101110"

Comment: okay it works now, but it is reading everything even the html tags and javascript, is there a way to only extract the text that is available in the page? @Daid Scott

Comment: A simple [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) would also work.

Comment: @mike, there is not simple solution for that. What you are requesting there is an HTML parser. Any meaningful HTML parser would be pretty decently complex and not reduceable to a single question. I'd recommend parsing the file with something like beautiful soup and then processing out the information you want to keep. What you are talking about is not a direct conversion. It requires parsing and processing.